# cx_freeze with python 3.x EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I fear i may be repeating a previous post but I dont understand the other posts at all so maybe this will provide a better explanation.

Ive created a file, want to use cx_freeze to create a lil MSI exe to install it wherever.

py file to run the build is this

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':base = 'Win32GUI'

opts = 'include_files':['raftlogo.gif'],'includes:["re"]
setup(  name = "Glass Calculator",
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'Raft Furniture - Glass Calculator',
    author = 'Lewis Tabone',\
    options = {'build_exe':opts},
    executables = [Executable('Glass Calculator.py',base= base)])
```

basically straight copied from a book that says this is how it should be written, but when i try and execute it with >>>python creator.py build as per the instructions, i get all kinds of crazy errors, EOL errors, syntax complaints, string literals.

I simply dont know enough about how this is supposed to be written to correct it.

Thanks in advance.

Further Additions:-

After using a completely different sequence i got it to build the list.

Only problem is that the EXE does not work error is as follows:-

Traceback(most recent call last):
File"C:\python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\console.py", line 27, in exec(code,m.**dict**)File"Glass Calculator.py",line 7, in  File "C:\python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py",line 3406,in__init__ Image.**init**(self,'photo',name,cnf,master,**kw)File"C:\Python33\lib\tikinter__init__.py",line3362,in__init__self.tlk.call(('image','create',imgtype,name,)+options)_tkinter.tclerror:couldnt open "raftlogo.gift": no such file or directory

Quite frankly i have no idea. Please help!

Comment: The first error: you're missing a quotation mark at the end of `'includes'`. The second one: you need to look in the right place for data files when your program is frozen - see [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this was that the folder to build a file list from was not all together with Python in Pythons C:\ directory. Do that and use the correct version of cx_Freeze as detailed on the other question i posted and you will have no problem.